# how to Difference between two date SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to find difference between two date . in database i have two columns transaction date and submitted Date . how to find how long to take to submit after transaction date approved

```
Employee   transaction Date      Submit date 
Kenya        01-06-2019          22-06-2019
Sandy        02-07-2019          15-07-2019
```

but i want get how long to take submit after transaction date

```
   Employee   transaction Date      Submit date     difference Date
    Kenya        01-06-2019          22-06-2019      21 days 
    Sandy        02-07-2019          15-07-2019      13 days
```

how to find this ? any one help me  ?

Comment: these are not valid sqlserver dates, so datediff() will not work, need to convert it first.

Comment: What is the data type for both the column `transaction Date` and `Submit Date` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT
    Employee,
    transaction_date,
    submit_date,
    DATEDIFF(day, transaction_date, submit_date) AS difference
FROM yourTable;
```

If you want the literal output you showed us, then use:

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(day, transaction_date, submit_date) AS varchar(max)) + ' days' AS difference
```

Comment: Again, you are assuming that just because you see non ISO date strings, that the columns must be text.  It has been my experience on SO that most of the time this is not the case.

Comment: Well, I'm sure OP will copy and paste actual data, rather than typing each date himself.

Comment: Are you aware that not all database tools would always output a date column in an ISO format?

Comment: far as I know this will not work on sql server engine.